# How do I serve from Cloudfront’s cache ONLY when there are origin errors?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I have a website that currently uses Cloudfront and WAF with Heroku origin.

At the moment, I do not cache anything in CF (using origin no-cache header) and currently only use WAF.

I don’t currently cache anything because of the nature of the content, which needs to be real-time from the origin DB.

Question: Despite the content needing to be real-time from the origin DB, can I still configure CF to cache the object and serve them ONLY if the origin is unavailable?

So failing over to cached objects but otherwise serve from origin.

Thanks.